# Does $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n<\infty$ imply $\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{n=1}^ma_n<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n<\infty\tag{1}$$
Can we deduce $$\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^ma_n}_{=:b_m}<\infty\;?$$ $(1)$ implies that $s:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n<\infty$. Thus, $b_m\le sm$. However, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\ne0$, then $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m a_n\ne0$ and $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^m a_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Can we deduce $$\sup_{m\in\mathbb{N}}b_m<\infty\;?$$

Comment: $\{b_m\}$ is bounded because it is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

False:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}6 &\text{(converges)} \\
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n^2} &\ge \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{m^2} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1m &\text{(diverges)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

if it is positive defined, $>\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}a_1$ which is divergent.. (if $a_1 =0$ we can change it with another $a_j \neq 0$).

Comment: There is no assumption of $a_n$ being positive.

Comment: i gave a huge class of counter example.. But Julian's answer is finished everything..